# F# determine if a number is an Armstrong number

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write an fsharp function to see if a number is an "armstrong" number:

A positive integer is an Armstrong number if it is equal to the sum of the cubes of its digits – e.g., the first such number is 1 and the second is 153.

for example. 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153

is there a way in fsharp to extract the individual digits of a number so I can cube them and then add their cubed results together?

Comment: The same way you'd do it in any other language - divide by `10` untill you get `0` as a result while storing every reminder.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by plenty of ways and rich `F#` and `.Net` libraries are at your service.

For example, you may convert your candidate number to string, then to character array, then each array element back to digit getting individual digits of the original number as array:

```
let asDigitArray n =
    n.ToString().ToCharArray()
    |> Array.map (System.Char.GetNumericValue >> System.Convert.ToInt32)
```

Checking in FSI

```
 > asDigitArray 12345;;
 val it : int [] = [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5|]
```

Besides, this approach works not just for `int`, but for `long` and `biginteger` arguments too, so you may use `asDigitArray` function for investigating really big Armstrong number candidates:

```
> asDigitArray 1234567898765L;;
val it : int [] = [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 8; 7; 6; 5|]
> asDigitArray 112233445566778899I;;
val it : int [] = [|1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6; 6; 7; 7; 8; 8; 9; 9|]
```